# What is the difference between npm remove and npm uninstall?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This documentation details out what [npm uninstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall) does however in some stackoverflow answers, I see some people use `npm remove <package-name>` and I have used `npm remove` also to remove a package from my project. However, I don't know the difference. Please can someone explain simply the difference between `npm uninstall <package-name>` and `npm remove <package-name>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference.

`remove` is just an alias for the *npm* `uninstall` command:

```
$ npm remove --help
npm uninstall [<@scope>/]<pkg>[@<version>]... [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--no-save]

aliases: un, unlink, remove, rm, r
```